# Java display invalid characters?

Tags: java, encryption, text, utf-8, aes

I have written a program the performs the standard AES S-Box encryption.  my problem is that when I encrypt the message it is supposed to write the text to a JTextArea, but it just shows a bunch of little square boxes and when I try to save it to a text document it just makes a bunch of question marks in the text file.  how can I make it display the encrypted text?  or can I even have it automatically write it to a text document without it creating a bunch of question marks?

I think that I have to use utf-8 text encoding but I have no idea how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your text is encrypted as binary data.  While encrypted it is not in any character set and cannot be rendered as text.  If you want a way to view it, you could Base64 encode the encrypted data.

See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64

Comment: already have base64 method incorporated, thanks tho i didn't know :P i am relatively new to more advanced cryptography, ill just display the binary

Comment: @user1718720 you can display the binary encoding (`0` and `1` characters) but I would rather display them in hexadecimal format. One way to do this is to use `String.format("%02X", byteValue)`. Relatively slow, but who cares with Gigahertz processors nowadays. Understanding the difference of bytes, byte arrays and [tag:encoding] and [tag:character-encoding] is essential for cryptography.

Answer (score 1):

The output of the algorithm will not be a valid text in the general case.

If you need to manipulate it as text you can encrypt it in **base-64** which uses only valid ASCII characters.